# How to find maximum value in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview, max

I load data that has positive and negative values like 0.0012, -0.00034 and so on. How I want to find max values from the data? i refer this website but error [link](https://1bestcsharp.blogspot.com/2016/04/csharp-datagridview-maximum-column-value.html)

```
 double max = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (max < double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString()))
            {
                max = double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
            }
        }

        textBoxMax.Text = max.ToString();
```

[image: This is the error]
[image]

What should i change in my code to get the max. value? I want to display them in the textBox.

Comment: how many columns you have in gridview?

Comment: In the code example it's `Cells[1]`, but in the screenshot it's `Cells[2]`.

Comment: If you want to find the maximum value then you should use `double.MinValue` to start with, not `0`. Likewise use `MaxValue` when looking for the minimum.

Comment: The error message is telling you that the index is outside the valid range but you appear to have made no effort to determine what the index or the valid range are.

Comment: oh sorry i forgot to change it, i just try and error, there i hve 2 column.

Comment: how to use `double.MinValue` ? @jmcilhinney

Comment: Wouldn't it be much simpler to do the search in the actual underlying data (`List<T>`, `DataTable`, whatever you used) than in the `DataGridView` control?

Comment: I told you to use it instead of zero. Are you seriously suggesting that you can't do that? You're not making any effort at all so I'm not either.

Comment: I try sir but still error. its say "SystemNullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption that you are populating your `DataGridView` from an underlying `DataTable` (I appreciate this might be a big assumption), you can simply get a max of the column using Linq:

```
var maxDouble = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row[1]).Max();
```

Comment: sir its say 'Datatable does not contain a definition for AsEnumerable'. I add `using System.Data.DataSetExtensions;` but still the DataSetExtensions show error

Comment: `using System.Data;` should be enough. Are you sure you are using a `DataTable` object?